# How to dynamically choose a DbContext for API endpoint method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, api, database-connection

I developed and API that uses a helper class to get the database context for each endpoint function. Now I'm trying to write unit tests for each endpoint and I want to use an In-memory db in my unit test project.

The issue I'm running into is that in order to call the API functions I had to add a constructor to my API controller class. This would allow me to pass the dbContext of the in-memory db to the controller function for it to use. However, since the adding of the constuctor I got the following error when attempting to hit the endpoint:

```
"exceptionMessage": "Unable to resolve service for type 'AppointmentAPI.Appt_Models.ApptSystemContext' while attempting to activate 'AppointmentAPI.Controllers.apptController'."
```

**UPDATE**

controller.cs

```
 public class apptController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApptSystemContext _context;

        public apptController(ApptSystemContext dbContext)
        {
            _context = dbContext;
        }


        #region assingAppt
        /*
         * assignAppt()
         *
         * Assigns newly created appointment to slot
         * based on slotId
         *
         */
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/appt/assignAppt")]
        public string assignAppt([FromBody] dynamic apptData)
        {
            int id = apptData.SlotId;
            string json = apptData.ApptJson;
            DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

            using (_context)
            {
               var slot = _context.AppointmentSlots.Single(s => s.SlotId == id);

                // make sure there isn't already an appointment booked in appt slot
                if (slot.Timestamp == null)
                {
                    slot.ApptJson = json;
                    slot.Timestamp = timeStamp;

                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    return "Task Executed\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "There is already an appointment booked for this slot.\n" +
                           "If this slot needs changing try updating it instead of assigning it.";
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

UnitTest.cs

```
using System;
using Xunit;
using AppointmentAPI.Controllers;
using AppointmentAPI.Appt_Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace XUnitTest
{
    public abstract class UnitTest1
    {
        protected UnitTest1(DbContextOptions<ApptSystemContext> contextOptions)
        {
            ContextOptions = contextOptions;

            SeedInMemoryDB();
        }

        protected DbContextOptions<ApptSystemContext> ContextOptions { get; }

        private void SeedInMemoryDB()
        {
            using(var context = new ApptSystemContext(ContextOptions))
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var seventh = new AppointmentSlots
                {
                    SlotId = 7,
                    Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-05-19 00:00:00.000"),
                    Time = TimeSpan.Parse("08:45:00.0000000"),
                    ApptJson = null,
                    Timestamp = null
                };

                context.AppointmentSlots.Add(seventh);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            DbContextOptions<ApptSystemContext> options;
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApptSystemContext>();
            builder.UseInMemoryDatabase();
            options = builder.Options;

            var context = new ApptSystemContext(options);

            var controller = new apptController(context);

            // Arrange
            var request = new AppointmentAPI.Appt_Models.AppointmentSlots
            {
                SlotId = 7,
                ApptJson = "{'fname':'Emily','lname':'Carlton','age':62,'caseWorker':'Brenda', 'appStatus':'unfinished'}",
                Timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-06-25 09:34:00.000")
            };

            string expectedResult = "Task Executed\n";

            // Act
            var response = controller.assignAppt(request);

            Assert.Equal(response, expectedResult);

        }
    }
}
```

InMemoryClass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data.Common;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AppointmentAPI.Appt_Models;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace XUnitTest
{
    public class InMemoryClass1 : UnitTest1, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly DbConnection _connection;

        public InMemoryClass1()
            :base(
                 new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApptSystemContext>()
                    .UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDB())
                    .Options
            )
        {
            _connection = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(ContextOptions).Connection;
        }

        private static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDB()
        {
            var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");

            connection.Open();

            return connection;
        }

        public void Dispose() => _connection.Dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: It is good that you have injected the dbcontext as dependency to controller. You also need to register the dbcontext in startup.cs and for unit testing you should use mocking.

Comment: Why you are using ConnectionHelper.getApptConnection()? Why not use the dependency injection for that also?

Comment: What's the trade offs for in-memory vs mocking?

Comment: In-memory DBContext is actually a way of mocking the actual DBContext. With mocking you don't need to depend on the actual implementation of In-memory Dbcontext. The data and behavior of DBContext can be completed mocked based on the use case you are testing. If you are using In-memory Dbcontext you need to worry about the data being shared between two test cases. Again it all depends on how you use In-memory Dbcontext in unit test. But initializing the context using context helper is not the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

The exception suggests that you haven't registered your DBContext in your Startup.cs (as mentioned above).  I'd also suggest that you change the name of your private readonly property to something other than DbContext (which is the class name and can get confusing) 
 Use something like this:

```cs
private readonly ApptSystemContext _context;
```

Besides that, your approach should be changed.

First, you will set the connection string when you register the DBContext.  Just let dependency injection take care of that for you.  Your controller should look like this:

```cs
        public apptController(ApptSystemContext dbContext)
        {
            _context = dbContext;
        }
```

The dbContext won't be null if you register it in Startup.

Next, unit testing is a tricky concept, but once you write your Unit test, you'll start to understand a little better.

You've said that you want to use the SQL In Memory db for unit testing, which is a good approach (be aware that there are limitations to SQL In Mem like no FK constraints).  Next, I assume you want to test your Controller, so, since you MUST pass in a DBContext in order to instantiate your Controller, you can create a new DBContext instance that is configured to use the In Memory Database.

For example

```cs
public void ApptControllerTest()
{
   //create new dbcontext
   DbContextOptions<ApptSystemContext> options;
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApptSystemContext>();
        builder.UseInMemoryDatabase();
        options = builder.Options;

    var context = new ApptSystemContext(options);

   //instantiate your controller
   var controller = new appController(context);

   //call your method that you want to test
   var retVal = controller.assignAppt(args go here);
}
```

Change the body of the method to this:

```cs
public string assignAppt([FromBody] dynamic apptData)
        {
            int id = apptData.SlotId;
            string json = apptData.ApptJson;
            DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

            using (_context)
            {
               var slot = _context.AppointmentSlots.Single(s => s.SlotId == id);

                // make sure there isn't already an appointment booked in appt slot
                if (slot.Timestamp == null)
                {
                    slot.ApptJson = json;
                    slot.Timestamp = timeStamp;

                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    return "Task Executed\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "There is already an appointment booked for this slot.\n" +
                           "If this slot needs changing try updating it instead of assigning it.";
                }
            }
        }
```

Another suggestion, don't use a dynamic object as the body of a request unless you are absolutely forced to do so.  Using a dynamic object allows for anything to be passed in and you lose the ability to determine if a request is acceptible or not.

Comment: Thanks for the the in depth explanation! This is my first time writing unit tests for any type of project. I added your suggestions to my code but then I get an error in the controller when trying to assign the variable `slot`. The error when running the test is: 

`Message: System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements`

I've also updated my code above to show all the files I'm currently working with.  After your suggestions do I still need the file InMemoryClass.cs?

Comment: To fix the exception, use .FirstOrDefault() instead of .Single() in assignAppt().  So change to this:   var slot = _context.AppointmentSlots.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SlotId == id);